# failed to parse JSON input

Tags: curl

I'm trying to POST a configuration file to vault and i'm getting `{"errors":["failed to parse JSON input: invalid character 'a' in numeric literal"]}` error. The file is not in JSON format. Any thoughts?

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST --upload-file "$HOME/config"  url-to-where-it-should-post/sample_deployment/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following configuration to push a yaml file to Hashicorp Vault.

**For pushing the yaml file directly:**

```
curl -k -H 'X-Vault-Token: <vault_token>' -X POST --data @test.yaml https:///v1/secret/foo/bar"
```

**If you would like to encode the file before pushing to Vault:**

```
base64 test.yaml | curl -k -H "X-Vault-Token: <vault_token>" -X POST --data @- https://<vault_host>/v1/secret/foo/bar
```

In the above command, the output of base64 will be passed on to the '@-'. The  '-' stands for take your value from stdin and this case it is the bash output.

**For testing if the secret got pushed:**

```
curl -s -k -H 'X-Vault-Token: <vault_token>' https://<vault_host>/v1/secret/foo/bar
```